# Resizing a screenshot to be attached to an email

Tags: android, eclipse, resize, screenshot

I am currently building this Android application, where I will be taking a screenshot of a "TableLayout" and then emailing it as an attachment. Here is the part of the code which takes the screenshot.

However, when I try to attach the file, using the following code, it says that "File Size Too Large for Attachment". Can anyone suggest any other measures that I can take, apart from Bitmap.Compress, in order to make my file size even smaller? Thanks in advance!

```
private void getScreen()
            {
                View content = findViewById(R.id.TransactionLog);
                content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                content.buildDrawingCache(true);

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(content.getDrawingCache());
                content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
                         File.separator + "whatever2.png");



                        try 
                            {
                                file.createNewFile();
                                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, ostream);
                                ostream.flush();
                                ostream.close();

                            } 
                        catch (Exception e) 
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29):

> public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap (Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int
>   dstHeight, boolean filter)
>   Since: API Level 1
>
> Creates a new bitmap, scaled from an existing bitmap.
>   Parameters
>    *src*       - The source bitmap.
>    *dstWidth*  - The new bitmap's desired width.
>    *dstHeight* - The new bitmap's desired height.
>    *filter*    - true if the source should be filtered.

FYI, the quality parameter passed to compress does not affect the file size when you are using `CompressFormat.PNG`.  Try using `CompressFormat.JPEG` instead, then try different quality values.

Alternatively, try this:
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/

Comment: I think this should work. But can you pls explain a bit more about the "src" parameter? Like, what value should I pass for this one in particular?

Comment: Read the API documentation that I linked to in my answer.  It shows you that the 'src' parameter needs to be a Bitmap, so you can pass in your bitmap variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried use a higher value for the quality parameter? (currently you're using 0 and it could go up to 100).

I suggest trying 80.

```
 boolean success = bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, ostream);
```

Don't forget to test if it was successful (log the return value of that method).

You can also try to use another format (jpeg?).

To make things simpler, I suggest you to try to save it to the sdcard first and check if the size is something you'd be expecting. You might have some problem on the code that sends the email or it might not let you send large attachments.

Comment: I wonder if setting quality to 0 will make it not compress at all.

Comment: Unfortunately increasing the quality increases the size of the file as well...I had it at 100 before and from then onwards the file was not being attached due to its size.

Comment: FYI, the quality parameter is ignored when you are compressing with CompressFormat.PNG (as it is a lossless compression algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

How big is your image?  An image made from an app, saved as a png, assuming its not a screenshot of a 'picture', should be pretty small.  FAR smaller than what email should be able to accept, unless there's an arbitrarily small attachment size.

If what's in your table is an image, or has quite a bit of variance, you might consider jpeg instead of png.  Otherwise, my guess is something else is going on.

Comment: This is what is confusing me as well. My table just has 5 columns and five rows of data in it. Hence its screenshot shouldn't be that large either. However, every time my email function opens, there is a small toast at the bottom of the screen saying that the file is too large. And the surprising part is, I know the file exists or else the "sendmail" function wouldn't have been called at all....however, I cannot physically access the file using DDMS.

Comment: If your file is on the sdcard, you can access it.  Use adb shell, then command line over (cd /mnt/sdcard;ls -l what*).  Also, just a suggestion.  Rather than 

new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
                         File.separator + "whatever2.png")

do 

new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "whatever2.png")

The first arg is a File object, which acts as the parent.  Easier to do (ish).

Comment: What content is actually in the table?  Just text?  The png output would be quite small.  I'm pretty sure something else is going on.